# angular ngFor iteration

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have problem with iteration in div in my modal

```
 public openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(PreviewModalComponent, {
      width: "60%",
    });
  }
```

```
<div class="hello">
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>bye</div>
    <div>{{text}}</div>
    <div>{{heroes[0].name}}</div>


    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        adsadasdsadsads
        {{hero.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

evrythink work except div with ngFor

```
 export class PreviewModalComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes = [];
  text: string = "cat";
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.headers = ["1", "imie", "nazwisko", "dsadsa"];

    this.heroes = [
      { id: 1, name: "Superman" },
      { id: 2, name: "Batman" },
      { id: 5, name: "BatGirl" },
      { id: 3, name: "Robin" },
      { id: 4, name: "Flash" },
    ];
  }
```

Additionaly this element doesnt exist in DOM

Comment: Which version are you using? You can use *ngIf="heroes && heroes.length>0"

Comment: 15.1.4 this is  content of dialog i am going to edit it in description

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Please provide more detail what problem you got.

Comment: I would like to, but I don't get any errors, and yet the element doesn't exist in dom.  the main problem is that unexpectedly ngfor doesn't work

Comment: I have created [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf37sr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). This works fine.

Answer (score -1):

the declaration of heroes is incorrect try this in your ts file :

```
 export class PreviewModalComponent implements OnInit {
      text: string = "cat";
       heroes = [
          { id: 1, name: "Superman" },
          { id: 2, name: "Batman" },
          { id: 5, name: "BatGirl" },
          { id: 3, name: "Robin" },
          { id: 4, name: "Flash" },
        ];
      ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.headers = ["1", "imie", "nazwisko", "dsadsa"];
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure? Now i got error "Cannot find name 'heroes'".

Comment: i have edited the answer, i copied your code and i forgot to put the declaration of Heroes above the   ngOnInit() , try it again

Comment: How is the declaration/definition/initialization of the OP wrong?

Comment: Hi @Philipp Meissner, because the DOM generate the data before the ts file so we should put the array decalration out of the  ngOnInit() , read more about it https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi thanks for help, but it still doesnt work, of course now it is declared correctly, but ngFor still doesn't work

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi The variable was well declared and initialized (`heroes = []`) and later re-declared and populated in the ngOnInit. Looks fine to me.